# How do I access a deeply nested property of this object?

Tags: javascript

Here is an object:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://company/api/data/v8.2/$metadata#EntityDefinitions(608861bc-50a4-4c5f-a02c-21fe1943e2cf)/Attributes/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.StateAttributeMetadata(LogicalName,OptionSet)","value":[
    {
      "LogicalName":"statecode","MetadataId":"cdc3895a-7539-41e9-966b-3f9ef805aefd","OptionSet@odata.context":"http://vsevm.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com/Xypex/api/data/v8.2/$metadata#EntityDefinitions(608861bc-50a4-4c5f-a02c-21fe1943e2cf)/Attributes(cdc3895a-7539-41e9-966b-3f9ef805aefd)/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.StateAttributeMetadata/OptionSet/$entity","OptionSet":{
        "MetadataId":"88fa5ad0-2a4b-4281-ac9c-b4e71fb77920","HasChanged":null,"Description":{
          "LocalizedLabels":[
            {
              "Label":"Status of the contact.","LanguageCode":1033,"IsManaged":true,"MetadataId":"fc7cf5df-8503-46e3-85b2-6c0ac68bc912","HasChanged":null
            }
          ],"UserLocalizedLabel":{
            "Label":"Status of the contact.","LanguageCode":1033,"IsManaged":true,"MetadataId":"fc7cf5df-8503-46e3-85b2-6c0ac68bc912","HasChanged":null
          }
        },"DisplayName":{
          "LocalizedLabels":[
            {
              "Label":"Status","LanguageCode":1033,"IsManaged":true,"MetadataId":"37c73b95-afd6-4d25-9ded-3691db6ce56b","HasChanged":null
            }
          ],"UserLocalizedLabel":{
            "Label":"Status","LanguageCode":1033,"IsManaged":true,"MetadataId":"37c73b95-afd6-4d25-9ded-3691db6ce56b","HasChanged":null
          }
        },"IsCustomOptionSet":false,"IsGlobal":false,"IsManaged":true,"IsCustomizable":{
          "Value":true,"CanBeChanged":false,"ManagedPropertyLogicalName":"iscustomizable"
        },"Name":"contact_statecode","OptionSetType":"State","IntroducedVersion":null,"Options":[
          {
            "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.StateOptionMetadata","Value":0,"Label":{
              "LocalizedLabels":[
                {
                  "Label":"Active","LanguageCode":1033,"IsManaged":true,"MetadataId":"4754c2fa-2241-db11-898a-0007e9e17ebd","HasChanged":null
                }
              ],"UserLocalizedLabel":{
                "Label":"Active","LanguageCode":1033,"IsManaged":true,"MetadataId":"4754c2fa-2241-db11-898a-0007e9e17ebd","HasChanged":null
              }
            },"Description":{
              "LocalizedLabels":[

              ],"UserLocalizedLabel":null
            },"Color":null,"IsManaged":true,"MetadataId":null,"HasChanged":null,"DefaultStatus":1,"InvariantName":"Active"
          },{
            "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.StateOptionMetadata","Value":1,"Label":{
              "LocalizedLabels":[
                {
                  "Label":"Inactive","LanguageCode":1033,"IsManaged":true,"MetadataId":"4954c2fa-2241-db11-898a-0007e9e17ebd","HasChanged":null
                }
              ],"UserLocalizedLabel":{
                "Label":"Inactive","LanguageCode":1033,"IsManaged":true,"MetadataId":"4954c2fa-2241-db11-898a-0007e9e17ebd","HasChanged":null
              }
            },"Description":{
              "LocalizedLabels":[

              ],"UserLocalizedLabel":null
            },"Color":null,"IsManaged":true,"MetadataId":null,"HasChanged":null,"DefaultStatus":2,"InvariantName":"Inactive"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am accessing this object using JavaScript. Id like to access the value of "Label" within this LocalizedLabel.

```
"Label":{
              "LocalizedLabels":[
                {
                  "Label":"Active","LanguageCode":1033,"IsManaged":true,"MetadataId":"4754c2fa-
2241-db11-898a-0007e9e17ebd","HasChanged":null
                    }
}
```

Comment: start at whatever the javascript object is you've parsed the JSON to ..

Comment: Then what??????

Comment: how are you "using JavaScript to parse it?"

Comment: I tried object.value[0].OptionSet and got undefined

Comment: `I tried` - well, how is `object` being assigned? because `whateveryourobjectis.value[0].OptionSet.Options[0].Label` should be what you're after

Comment: Note that [there ain't no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). There's JSON, which is a string representation of an object (typically used for data transfer), and then when you parse that string you get an object.

Comment: No matter what I do, value[0].OptionSet is undefined

Comment: Well I just copy pasted your JSON string into a console, giving it the name `object`, then I can access `object.value[0].OptionSet` without any issue, so you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the different layers in a Javascript object is pretty straight forward once you get the trick. Essentially, **when you want to go one level deeper into an object, you use "." followed by the key name**.
Ex:

```
object = {"key1": { "key2": "some value"}}
value = object.key1.key2 //returns "some value"
```

This will return the value associated to that key. If that value is another object, you can iterate the process. If that value is an array, well, just operate on it like you would on any other array.

Combine that with usual array access techniques:

```
object = {"key1": 
             { "key2": 
                 [ 
                     {"key3": "some value"},
                     {"key3": "another value"}
                 ]
         }}
list = object.key1.key2 // returns  "[ {"key3": "some value"},{"key3": "another attribute"}]"

listElement = object.key1.key2[0] // return "{"key3": "some value"}"

value = object.key1.key2[0].key3 // returns "some value"

otherValue = object.key1.key2[1].key3 // returns "another value"
```

etc.

**edit:** As pointed in the comment below, JSON is simply a formatting, not a data type in itself. What you want to know is here is how to operate on javascript objects and arrays. (In other words, JSON is a way to write objects and/or arrays as a string that is syntactically correct javascript, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) for more details)

Comment: Note that there's no JSON in this answer, just nested objects/arrays.

Comment: Well spotted, my mistake. Edited my answer, thanks for pointing that out.